# Tkinter 60 seconds timer

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to do a 60 timer for a project but i am stuck here. My variable temp doesnt update itself on my window everytime i go trough it. Anyhelp would be great.

```
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("300x250")
root.title("Time Counter")

Frame=tkinter.Frame(root)
Frame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

Label1=tkinter.Label(Frame,text="Timer")
Label1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

def timer(*args,**kwargs):
    temp=int(temps.get())
    while temp>-1:
        temps.set(str(temp))
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        temp-=1

temps=tkinter.StringVar()
temps.set("60")
temps.trace("w",timer)
label=tkinter.Label(Frame,textvariable=temps)
label.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
label.after(1000,timer)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Avoid using while loop in main thread of tkinter application.  Also why do you `trace` the variable? It may cause recursive error.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you just remove `trace` and `after` and call the function directly:

```
temps=tkinter.StringVar()
temps.set("60")
label=tkinter.Label(Frame,textvariable=temps)
label.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
timer()
```

Adding the `timer()` function to the `trace` of your StringVar leads to the function being called whenever the value of `temps` changes. This can't work since the function changes the value, itself.